# Livewire Freeze After Close Modal

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

when i closeModal, modal cant close correctly, when close modal, my page freeze on browser.

any solution for this?

Here is my controller:

```
class LaporIzinTable extends DataTableComponent
{
    public $selectedItems;
    public $modalIsOpen = false;
    protected $model = LaporIzin::class;


    public function configure(): void
    {
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
    }

    public function bulkActions(): array
    {
        return [
            'openModal' => 'Hapus Data'
        ];
    }

    public function openModal()
    {
        $selectedItems = $this->getSelected();
        $this->modalIsOpen = true;
        $this->emit('openModal', "path-to-modal", ['selectedItems' => $selectedItems]);
    }

    public function closeModal()
    {
        $this->modalIsOpen = false; // Set modalIsOpen to false when closing the modal.
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal');
    }
```

Here is my full blade:

```
@if($modalIsOpen)

<!-- Modal -->
<div wire:ignore.self class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" wire:click="closeModal"><i class="flaticon-cancel-12"></i> Batal</button>
                <button href="#" wire:click="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Pilih modal dengan ID "exampleModal" dan buka secara otomatis
    $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
  });
</script>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('close-modal', event => {
    $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
})
</script>

@endif
```

I want, after wire:click="closeModal", modal close correctly, NOT FREEZE IN BROWSER

Comment: Diloge is javascript api you shpuld keep it in browser. Or make it false with some delay in livewire

Comment: How? Can you give sample?

Comment: Don't use Livewire that i am saying if you still want to use set modalIsOpen delay it 100ms or 200ms

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ check this and only wire:click when needed also add close dialogue.